# Communication between private IP addresses over the Internet

Tags: ip, private

Suppose we have messenger like GTalk, Skype etc running on two different PCs(A and B) which have **private IP addresses** but connected to Internet through some ISP. The two PCs could be located in different parts of the world. Now its possible to send messages and make VoIP calls between A and B.

This obviously uses server for communication establishment. For text messages it could be routed through the server to reach A and B.

But for VoIP calls, I believe initial establishment would be taking help of server and later VoIP data would flow directly between A and B. Now, A and B both have private IP addresses.

So my question is how is it possible to communicate between A and B **directly over the Internet** who have private IP addresses ?

Is there any specific standard for this ? I am not talking about VoIP standard like RTP etc  but the mechanism to communicate over Internet using private IP addresses. In other words, I simply have a TCP client and TCP server running on A and B respectively. How can TCP client reach TCP server ?

I would like to know if messengers like GTalk, Yahoo, Skype and many of the Android applications like Viber, Kakoa talk, WhatsApp etc use any specific standard for this. And I have seen that these work almost always, calls between A and B work, located anywhere in the world.

It would be nice if somebody can share the architecture and the concepts involved.

[I did read about concepts like STUN and hole punching. But I don't see any specific way. And there is no guarantee that these would work depending on the NAT behavior]

Thank you.

Comment: It's all NAT. Typically happening at the end user's router.

Comment: Yes, NAT. But what are the protocols involved typically ? Say I have a TCP client and server, how would I connect from client to server ? Thanks.